# Spring WebFlux Controller default pools

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I need advice, there are two controller methods:

Method with body parameter

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Mono<SuccessEmptyResponse> withBody(@RequestBody CreatePhoneCode command) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                System.out.println("Current thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return SuccessEmptyResponse.getInstance();
            });
}
```

Method without body

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Mono<SuccessEmptyResponse> methodWithoutBody() {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("Current thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return SuccessEmptyResponse.getInstance();
    });
}
```

Method test1 prints log "Current thread **reactor-http-nio-n**"

Method test2 prints log "Current thread **parallel-n**"

How we can see, by default spring uses parallel pool for handle methods without body, and event loop pool for handle requests with body. I understand that i can change pool by call method subscribeOn and publishOn, but i have two question.

1. Why spring has this logic by default?
2. Can i use parallel worker for handle requests with body by default (without change pool manually?).

Comment: The one with the request body already has a predefined reactive flow as it needed to deserialize the request body, the one without doesn't. If you create a reactive flow each part can be executed by a different thread (as you notice here). So it isn't so much Spring but rather a result of what is done before this controller method is even being called.

Comment: Your code will not be executed in the written place. In the future, another task will be to subscribe to your mono, and that thread will be used. In the reactive environment, thread management differs significantly from the classic WebMvc model with Tomcat. For example, you mustn't use any blocker methods, and not recommended to save any information into ThreadLocal because there is a good chance it will be run by a different thread than the one you saved.